# ffmpeg: smooth, stable timelapse videos from normal speed videos

Tags: ffmpeg, hdr, timelapse

For a one hour dash cam video in normal speed, is it possible to create a smooth timelapse video from it?

Most tutorials online I found about "timelapse + ffmpeg" are with static jpeg files combined into a timelapse video. These often result jiggle between frames, are the any specific parameters which would make the video looking very smooth & stable?

Should I just `setpts=0.5*PTS` for the trick? Any must-have or little-known tricks?

Update: this question is asking for specific programmable ffmpeg parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's the way specified in the [ffmpeg wiki: How to speed up / slow down a video](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video).

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:v "setpts=0.5*PTS" output.mkv`

`setpts` also supports expressions if you feel creative and want to speed up/ slow down based on a curve rather than a constant value.

Eg: `-filter:v "setpts=gauss(T/100)*PTS"`